# Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pytz-2017.2.dist-info'

Tags: command-line

I tried to install Django with `pip install Django==1.11.4`
but I face this error all the time:

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
status = self.run(options, args)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
prefix=options.prefix_path,
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 784, in install
**kwargs
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 851, in install
self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
isolated=self.isolated,
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 345, in move_wheel_files
clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 316, in clobber
ensure_dir(destdir)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 83, in ensure_dir
os.makedirs(path)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pytz-2017.2.dist-info'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, pip installs in `/usr/local`, which needs sudo permissions. Instead, whenever you are working with Python modules, use virtualenv. It's pretty easy:

1. Globally install Python virtualenv

   ```
   sudo pip install virtualenv
   ```
2. Create a virtualenv

   ```
   virtualenv Venv
   ```
3. Activate your virtualenv

   ```
   source Venv/bin/activate
   ```
4. Install Django locally in the virtualenv

   ```
   pip install django
   ```

This way you don't have to worry about modifying global Python modules and its much safer.

Answer (score 3):

@Sanchit's answer is spot-on. Virtual environment is the way to go if you manage different projects in your machine and does not want dependencies of one project interfering with the other.

In case you want to install a package in your system with locally installed pip without a virtual environment while you are getting a permission denied error, try installing the package for the current user alone. This can be done by appending the `--user` flag to your `pip install` command.

For example:

```
pip install Django==1.11.4 --user
```

Also, I wouldn't install `pip` packages using `sudo` permissions for two reasons:

1. SUDO might not be available to every user.
2. *SUDO seem to install packages for just the `root` user and not for current user (at least in my case - Ubuntu 16.04, OpenStack Cloud Instance)

*Might not apply to you. I've found it hard to reproduce.

Answer (score 2):

Pip is trying to install it in the /usr/local folder which requires admin permission. If you are admin and want to install it there run the same command with sudo:

```
sudo pip install Django==1.11.4
```

It will ask you for your password and that should be it.

edit: you can also use the pip's --user option but it will only be available for current user.