# pip commands are not working

Tags: pip

I tried running pip commands, for example: `pip install tweepy`. I'm getting these errors:

```
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'idnadata.py'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

You are using pip version 18.0, however version 18.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

[image: terminal screenshot]

Comment: Just to note, the first two lines are an error. The second two are a warning which is lower priority, and not related to the error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pytz-2017.2.dist-info'](https://askubuntu.com/questions/949136/permission-denied-usr-local-lib-python2-7-dist-packages-pytz-2017-2-dist-info)

Answer (score -1):

You should be using sudo with pip install, so instead of

```
pip install foo
```

It becomes

```
sudo pip install foo
```

Comment: Please don’t use sudo with pip. This can lead to confusing package dependency problems when using both pip and apt, and you don’t really want to install random code from PyPI to the system anyways. You should use the `--user` flag like it mentions.

Comment: Thanks @Steve, I'm new to this helping thing so I wasn't aware!

Comment: No worries, just wanted to mention that since I’ve spent many years dealing with all the different Python package managers. And I didn’t downvote btw :)